# Is there a way with GORM nested preloading to preload structs of an array on an item you are preloading?

Tags: go, go-gorm

My question is best described with a simple/relevant example. Given the structs below, is there a way that I can use nested preloading in GORM to populate models of an array on a preloaded model?

```
type OptionItem struct {
    gorm.Model
    blah    string
}

type OrderItem struct {
    gorm.Model

    OptionItems  []OrderOptionItem

    OrderID       uint                 `gorm:"column:order_id"`
    Order         Order
}

type OrderOptionItem struct {
    gorm.Model

    OrderItemID  uint                  `gorm:"column:order_item_id""`

    OptionItemID uint                  `gorm:"column:option_item_id"`
    OptionItem   OptionItem            `gorm:"auto_preload"`
}


func getOrderItemsByOrderID(orderID string) {

    var orderItems []OrderItem
    a.db.DB.
        Preload("Order", "id = (?)", orderID).
        Preload("OptionItems").
        Find(&orderItems)


    for _, oi := range orderItems {
        for _, ooi := range oi.OptionItems {
            // OptionItem on OrderOptionItem is not populated
            log.Println(ooi.OptionItem.ID)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The gorm tag on your `OptionItem` is invalid, it should be `gorm:"preload:true"`.

Alternatively, you can always preload nested association by `db.Preload("OptionItems.OptionItem")`.

p/s: It's hurt my eyes looking at those struct's names :D